# Create COM API, or similar, for Node.js app

Tags: c#, javascript, c++, node.js

I have written an application in JavaScript that runs on node.js.

Is it possible to create a [COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or similar, for a Node.js application?

For example, in C, C++, C#, etc, you can write an application, and then have another application, written in a different programming language, interact with your code via the [COM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I want to be able to do this for my JavaScript application. So that I could interact with it from another programming language. Is this possible?

Comment: But the COM API is horrible. If you want to interact with it in C or C++, why not use V8? What kind of library do you need?

Comment: It would be nice to write a library in JavaScript

Comment: @ putting it on hold: I don't see how this was to "recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource". It was to see if something is technically possible that I did not know. It is not an obviously documented thing.

Comment: “it would be nice to write a library in JavaScript” – if you’re talking about COM, once again, it is the *opposite* of nice. If you have a good reason to do this, look into V8, which is the engine Node.js runs off and which is easily extensible using C++. (I’m sure you could make that COM if you tried hard.) But otherwise, you should pick a more appropriate language.

Answer (score 1):

Calling javascript from an outside process is not part of the javascript specification standard.  As such, it is specific to a given javascript implementation.  `node.js` uses Google's V8 javascript engine and the embedding interface to that engine from a language like C++ is here: https://developers.google.com/v8/embed.

It does not use COM.  I believe there are some other JS engines that might offer a COM interface on Windows.

Some other things to look at:

javascript.net - integrates V8 to Microsoft's CLI language environment: https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net

Windows scripting engine COM interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xawadt95%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Mixing JS code and native code: http://athile.net/library/blog/?p=760